# Save shortcode array with WordPress Options API then output in another function

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, shortcode

**Note: While this is probably a simple fix, I'm new to using arrays and am completely stumped.**

I'm trying to save the data from a shortcode array via the Options API in WordPress, then call that array and use the data to create another array to hook into a plugin's function. It's a responsive slider plugin and I'm basically trying to attach a shortcode to it so I can create the slider on the backend and display it on the front end with a shortcode that looks like: `[responsive_slider slider_name="imageslider"]`.

The implementation documentation can be [found here](http://halgatewood.com/flexslider-hg/), and here's my code:

```
function responsive_gallery_shortcode($atts, $content=null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts( array('slider_name' => 'product_page') , $atts));
    foreach ($slider_name as $value) {
        update_option('_unique_slider_name', $value );
    }
    if(function_exists('show_flexslider_rotator')) 
        echo show_flexslider_rotator( $slider_name );

    add_image_size( $slider_name , '550', '250', true );
}
add_shortcode('responsive_gallery', 'responsive_gallery_shortcode');        

if (!function_exists('custom_set_flexslider_hg_rotators')) {
    function custom_set_flexslider_hg_rotators() {
        $slider_name = get_option('_unique_slider_name');

        foreach ($slider_name as $value) { 
            $rotators = array();
            $rotators[ $value ] = array( 'size' => $value );    
            return $rotators;
        }   
    }  
} 
add_filter('flexslider_hg_rotators', 'custom_set_flexslider_hg_rotators', 9999);
```

I'm getting an *"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"* error on both `foreach` functions. On the page where I have two shortcodes both errors show up twice. It seems as though `$slider_name` is a string instead of an array, but there's got to be a way to save it in the `update_option()` function so that it returns an array. I'm quite new to arrays, and I'm definitely struggling here. I've spent hours on this and have already received a little help on the WordPress side, but I'm not quite getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the shortcode attribute will arrive as a string, you need to convert it to an array first.

At the same time, as it has to be passed as a string, you'll need to use a separator so you can manage this.

And for all that, you'll need the PHP function [**`explode`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$string = "one,two";
$array = explode( ',', $string );
var_dump( $array );
```

*Results in:*

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'one' (length=3)
  1 => string 'two' (length=3)
```

And

```
$string = "one";
$array = explode( ',', $string );
var_dump( $array );
```

Results in:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'one' (length=3)
```

---

*PS: It's always worth to consult the PHP Manual and also the comments in each of its pages : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php*

---

**[update]**
There are many issues with your original code, check the comments of this revised version:

```
function responsive_gallery_shortcode($atts, $content=null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts( array('slider_name' => 'product_page') , $atts));

    // Convert string into array
    // Using comma as separator when writing the shortcode in the post
    $array_slider = explode( ',', $slider_name );

    // YOU DON'T NEED A `foreach` HERE
    //foreach ($array_slider as $value) {
        update_option('_unique_slider_name', $array_slider );
    //}

    // I DON'T KNOW WHAT THIS FUNCTIONS DOES
    // But in any case, being $array_slider an array, maybe it should be inside a `foreach`
    if(function_exists('show_flexslider_rotator')) 
        echo show_flexslider_rotator( $array_slider );

    // THIS DOESN'T MAKE SENSE
    // You're not supposed to be adding images sizes at each Shortcode call
    // And you are dealing with an array
    add_image_size( $slider_name , '550', '250', true );
}
add_shortcode('responsive_gallery', 'responsive_gallery_shortcode');        

if (!function_exists('custom_set_flexslider_hg_rotators')) {
    function custom_set_flexslider_hg_rotators() {
        // The option was already saved as array, so we can work directly with it
        $slider_name = get_option('_unique_slider_name');

        // YOU DON'T WANT TO DECLARE THE VARIABLE AT EACH STEP OF THE LOOP
        $rotators = array();
        foreach ($slider_name as $value) { 
            $rotators[ $value ] = array( 'size' => $value );    
        }   
        // RETURN THE VALUE ONLY AFTER COMPLETING THE LOOP
        return $rotators;
    }  
    // PUT THE FILTER HOOK INSIDE if(!function_exists())
    add_filter('flexslider_hg_rotators', 'custom_set_flexslider_hg_rotators', 9999);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm just trying to work through this right now. Using the example above, if I do $array = explode(), then the array is now stored in $array, correct? I'm trying to do a foreach statement that looks like `foreach ($array as $value) {   
    $rotators[ $value ] = array( 'size' => $value );  
 }` but it ends up only outputting the last value to be stored, just like it did with my function above. Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: @JeremiahPrummer, there are many issues with our original code, check the updated Answer.

Comment: Not working, but at this point I think it's just that the plugin I'm hooking into wasn't designed to work this way. I'm going to resort to manually adding it where needed as it's much easier (and more reliable) than trying to do it through a shortcode. Thanks for your help, you've taught me a lot.